# How to subtract every previous rows from the lead row to every five rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, subtraction, tapply

I have a larger data frame that has multiple columns and thousands of rows. I want to replace the value of every lead row by subtracting the previous row value from the lead row for every five rows of the data frame. For example, the first value should retain its value, the second row should be: `second row - first row`. Similarly, the sixth row should retain its value, however, the seventh row would be `seventh row - sixth row`. Here is an example data frame

```
DF = data.frame(A= c(1:11), B = c(11:21))
```

The outputput should be like below

```
> Output
    A  B
1   1 11
2   1  1
3   1  1
4   1  1
5   1  1
6   6 16
7   1  1
8   1  1
9   1  1
10  1  1
11 11 21
```

Comment: It may be better to check the `dplyr` version `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: my installed `dplyr` version is `‘0.8.0.1’`

Comment: Can you please update your version because it could affect

Comment: re-installed the package, its now ‘0.8.3’ version and got the results.however, I am also getting this warning:  `mutate_all()` ignored the following grouping variables:
Column `grp`
Use `mutate_at(df, vars(-group_cols()), myoperation)` to silence the message.

Comment: If it is a warning, it is a friendly message and not an error

Comment: Thanks, I actually didn't see that warning earlier, updated the post

Comment: Thank you @akrun and everyone else for providing very helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to create a grouping variable and then do the transformation with `diff`  which does the difference of adjacent elements of the columns selected in `mutate_all` (if only a subset of columns are needed either use `mutate_if` or `mutate_at`)

```
library(dplyr) #v_0.8.3
DF %>% 
   group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 5, n()))) %>% 
   mutate_all(~c(first(.), diff(.))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 11 x 2
#       A     B
#   <int> <int>
# 1     1    11
# 2     1     1
# 3     1     1
# 4     1     1
# 5     1     1
# 6     6    16
# 7     1     1
# 8     1     1
# 9     1     1
#10     1     1
#11    11    21
```

The above also gives a warning when we use `mutate_all` after `group_by` (previously it used to work - in the new versions, the correct syntax would be to use `mutate_at`

```
DF %>% 
   group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 5, n()))) %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~c(first(.), diff(.))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

Comment: Getting this error message while executing the code ``mutate_all()` ignored the following grouping variables:
Column `grp`
Use `mutate_at(df, vars(-group_cols()), myoperation)` to silence the message.
Error in select(., -grp) : unused argument (-grp)`

Comment: @Hydrologist  Is it on the same data you showed as I can't reproduce it with `dplyr_0.8.3`

Comment: I have different data but tried on the same data on my end. Getting same error

Comment: @Hydrologist  So, you are not getting the error with the data you showed, is that right?  Can you check the `str` of new data and compare with data showed.  I have a feeling that there are some group attributes causing it.  Can you `ungroup` and then do the `group_by` again

Comment: I am getting error with the same data using your code. I am adding a screen shot to your provided answer as I do not know if I can include it in my comment.

Comment: @Hydrologist  Do you have the same `dplyr` version or an older version

Comment: @Hydrologist  Can you update by editing it in your post

Answer (score 3):

```
f = function(d, n = 5) ave(d, ceiling(seq_along(d)/n), FUN = function(x) c(x[1], diff(x)))
data.frame(lapply(DF, f))
#    A  B
#1   1 11
#2   1  1
#3   1  1
#4   1  1
#5   1  1
#6   6 16
#7   1  1
#8   1  1
#9   1  1
#10  1  1
#11 11 21
```

Another option would be to create another data.frame with shifted rows and subtract directly

```
ind = ave(1:nrow(DF), ceiling(1:nrow(DF)/5), FUN = function(x) c(x[1], x[-length(x)]))
DF2 = DF[ind,] * replace(rep(1, nrow(DF)), diff(ind) == 0, 0)
DF - DF2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `%/%` the row number minus 1 by 5 to get the groups, then use `diff` to get the difference from the previous `x` (or 0 if there is no previous `x`) from `x` for all columns `x` for each group.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

DF[, lapply(.SD, function(x) diff(c(0, x)))
   , (1:nrow(DF) - 1) %/% 5][, -1]

#      A  B
#  1:  1 11
#  2:  1  1
#  3:  1  1
#  4:  1  1
#  5:  1  1
#  6:  6 16
#  7:  1  1
#  8:  1  1
#  9:  1  1
# 10:  1  1
# 11: 11 21
```

Or, as mentioned by @akrun, you could avoid `lapply` by replacing

```
lapply(.SD, function(x) diff(c(0, x)))
```

with

```
.SD - shift(.SD, fill = 0)
```

Another less serious option:

```
x <- DF[, !(.I - 1) %% 5]
DF*(1 + x) - DF[DF[, .I - !x]]

#      A  B
#  1:  1 11
#  2:  1  1
#  3:  1  1
#  4:  1  1
#  5:  1  1
#  6:  6 16
#  7:  1  1
#  8:  1  1
#  9:  1  1
# 10:  1  1
# 11: 11 21
```